# Curve class entries spilling out of page

Tags: curve-class

I intend to use the curve class for my CV but the entries are spilling out of page. Please help.

This is the code for main.tex

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e} 


\documentclass[a4paper,skipsamekey,11pt]{curve}

\usepackage{settings}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm,top=1.5cm,bottom=1.5cm}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\setlength{\footskip}{0.7cm}


\definecolor{SwishLineColour}{HTML}{106B21}
\definecolor{MarkerColour}{HTML}{8A1538}


\ifxetexorluatex % If you're using XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX,SmallCapsFeatures={Letters=SmallCaps,LetterSpace=5}]{Charis SIL}
\setsansfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Fira Sans}
\setmonofont{Inconsolata}
\else % If you're using pdfLaTeX or latex
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{breakcites}
\usepackage{fbb}
\usepackage[type1]{cabin}
\usepackage[varqu,varl]{zi4}

\fi
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage{fontawesome}

\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{svg.path}

\usepackage[tracking=smallcaps]{microtype}


\definecolor{orcidlogocol}{HTML}{A6CE39}
\tikzset{
    orcidlogo/.pic={
        \fill[orcidlogocol] svg{M256,128c0,70.7-57.3,128-128,128C57.3,256,0,198.7,0,128C0,57.3,57.3,0,128,0C198.7,0,256,57.3,256,128z};
        \fill[white] svg{M86.3,186.2H70.9V79.1h15.4v48.4V186.2z}
        svg{M108.9,79.1h41.6c39.6,0,57,28.3,57,53.6c0,27.5-21.5,53.6-56.8,53.6h-41.8V79.1z M124.3,172.4h24.5c34.9,0,42.9-26.5,42.9-39.7c0-21.5-13.7-39.7-43.7-39.7h-23.7V172.4z}
        svg{M88.7,56.8c0,5.5-4.5,10.1-10.1,10.1c-5.6,0-10.1-4.6-10.1-10.1c0-5.6,4.5-10.1,10.1-10.1C84.2,46.7,88.7,51.3,88.7,56.8z};
    }
}

\newcommand\orcidicon[1]{\href{https://orcid.org/#1}{\mbox{\scalerel*{
                \begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=-1,transform shape]
                \pic{orcidlogo};
                \end{tikzpicture}
}{|}}}}
        
        
        
        

\usepackage{natbib} %to compressed succcessive citations
\usepackage{bibentry} % use to insert full reference entries in the text


\newcommand*{\doi}[1]{DOI \href{https://doi.org/#1}{\texttt{#1}}}
\makeatletter
% expandable version of ...
\def\bibinfo#1{%
    \@ifundefined{bibinfo@X@#1}%
    {\@firstofone}
    {\csname bibinfo@X@#1\endcsname}}
\makeatother

\usepackage{url}
\def\UrlBreaks{\do\/\do-\do.}

\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}

\usepackage{hyperref} %hyperlink
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,linkcolor=black,citecolor=blue,urlcolor=blue} %change the color to black for print version

\makeatletter % <=======================================================
\def\@continuedname{}
\makeatother % <========================================================


\includecomment{fullonly}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\leftheader{%
    {\LARGE\bfseries\sffamily John Doe, PhD}
    
    \vspace{0.5cm}
    
    \makefield{\faUniversity}{\texttt{Institute of XXXXXXXX}}
        
    %\makefield{}{\texttt{College of xxxxxxxx}}
        
    \makefield{}{\texttt{University of XXXXX}}
    
    \makefield{}{\texttt{XXXXXXX}}
    
    \vspace{0.3cm}
    
    \makefield{\faEnvelopeO}{\texttt{jdoe@email.com}}
    
    \makefield{\faPhone}{\texttt{+000000000000}}
    
    \vspace{0.3cm}
    
    \makefield{\orcidicon{0000-0000-0000-0000}}{\texttt{ORCiD:0000-0000-0000-0000}}
    
    \vspace{0.5cm}
}

\rightheader{~}
\begin{fullonly}
    \photo[r]{photo.jpg}
    \photoscale{0.2}
\end{fullonly}

%\geometry{includefoot}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@evenfoot}{\footnotesize \textit{JDoe - CV as of {\today} \hfill \small \thepage/\pageref{LastPage}}}
\renewcommand{\@oddfoot}{\footnotesize \textit{JDoe - CV as of {\today} \hfill \small \thepage/\pageref{LastPage}}}
\makeatother



\title{Curriculum Vitae}

\begin{document}

    \bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}
    
    \nobibliography{references}
    
    \makeheaders[c]
    
    \makerubric{grants}


\end{document}
```

This is the code for grants.tex

```
\begin{rubric}{Grants, Fellowships and Scholarships}

\entry*[2015-2018] The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
\entry*[2012-2013] The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
\entry*[2003-2008] The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
\end{rubric}
```

Please see image[image: Compiled pdf]

This is the contents of the settings.sty

```
\RequirePackage{silence}
\WarningsOff[longtable]
\WarningsOff[array]

\usepackage{ifxetex,ifluatex}
\newif\ifxetexorluatex
\ifxetex
  \xetexorluatextrue
\else
  \ifluatex
    \xetexorluatextrue
  \else
    \xetexorluatexfalse
  \fi
\fi

\RequirePackage{graphicx}
\RequirePackage[hyphens]{url}
\RequirePackage[main=british]{babel}
%\RequirePackage{ragged2e}
\raggedright

\RequirePackage{fontawesome}

\newcommand{\smallcaps}[1]{\textsc{\lowercase{#1}}}

\RequirePackage[a4paper,nohead,nofoot,hmargin=1.5cm,vmargin=1.5cm]{geometry}
%\RequirePackage[a4paper,nohead,nofoot,left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
%\RequirePackage[a4paper,nohead,nofoot,width=16cm]{geometry}
\RequirePackage{relsize}
\RequirePackage[dvipsnames,svgnames]{xcolor}
\RequirePackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,shadows}

\RequirePackage{comment}
\definecolor{SwishLineColour}{HTML}{88AC0B}
\definecolor{MarkerColour}{HTML}{B6073F}


\RequirePackage{tikz}
\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
   \node[shape=circle,text=white,fill=MarkerColour!80!black,font=\sffamily\scriptsize\bfseries,inner sep=1pt,text height=1.35ex,minimum width=1.5em,text centered] (char) {#1};}}
   

\headerscale{1}
%\setlength{\headerspace}{6pt}
\rubricfont{\Large\bfseries\sffamily}
\setlength{\rubricspace}{2pt}
%\setlength{\rubricafterspace}{-9pt}
\setlength{\rubricafterspace}{-3pt}
\setlength{\subrubricspace}{3pt}
\setlength{\subrubricbeforespace}{4pt}
\def\@@rubrichead#1{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]%\
  \shade[left color=SwishLineColour!60!white, right color=white] rectangle (\@almosttextwidth,2.5pt);
  \node[font={\@rubricfont},inner sep=0pt,text ragged,anchor=south west,text depth=.5ex,text height=1.5ex] at (1pt,2pt) {#1};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  \vspace\rubricspace%
}

\subrubricfont{\large\bfseries\sffamily}
\subrubricalignment{l}

\newcommand{\makefield}[2]{\makebox[1.5em]{\color{MarkerColour!80!black}#1} #2\hspace{2em}}

\keyalignment{r}
\rubricalignment{l}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.25}
\urlstyle{tt}

\newcommand{\prefixmarker}[1]{\def\@prefixmarker{#1}}
\def\@prefixmarker{\relscale{.9}\faBookmark}

\prefix{%
  \hspace*{-1ex}
  \color{MarkerColour!80!black}\@prefixmarker%
  \hspace*{1ex}%
}

\newcommand{\makerubrichead}[1]{\vskip\baselineskip\@@rubrichead{#1}}





\newcommand{\myname}[2]{%
   \def\@mylastname{#1}%
   \def\@myfirstname{#2}%
}



\RequirePackage[colorlinks=true,allcolors=black,breaklinks=true]{hyperref}
```

Comment: Please add the package settings in order to  make your MWE compilable

Comment: Hi Simon. Thank you for the response. I have now included the contents of the settings.sty

Answer (score 1):

The file `settings.sty` loads many packages.

The command `\listfiles` before `\documentclass` will make a list of all the packages loaded at the end of the .log file.

For example, `geometry` was loaded by `settings.sty`, there is not need to do it again, etc.

So before adding another package to `settings.sty` check if it not already loaded to avoid conflicts. Remember the `hyperref` should be the last package to be loaded.

A simplified preamble makes the problem go away.

[image: b]

```
\listfiles
    
\documentclass[a4paper,skipsamekey,11pt]{curve}

\usepackage{settings}   

\usepackage{lipsum} 

\setlength{\footskip}{0.7cm}

\definecolor{SwishLineColour}{HTML}{106B21}
\definecolor{MarkerColour}{HTML}{8A1538}

\usepackage{scalerel}
\usetikzlibrary{svg.path}
\definecolor{orcidlogocol}{HTML}{A6CE39}
\tikzset{
    orcidlogo/.pic={
        \fill[orcidlogocol] svg{M256,128c0,70.7-57.3,128-128,128C57.3,256,0,198.7,0,128C0,57.3,57.3,0,128,0C198.7,0,256,57.3,256,128z};
        \fill[white] svg{M86.3,186.2H70.9V79.1h15.4v48.4V186.2z}
        svg{M108.9,79.1h41.6c39.6,0,57,28.3,57,53.6c0,27.5-21.5,53.6-56.8,53.6h-41.8V79.1z M124.3,172.4h24.5c34.9,0,42.9-26.5,42.9-39.7c0-21.5-13.7-39.7-43.7-39.7h-23.7V172.4z}
        svg{M88.7,56.8c0,5.5-4.5,10.1-10.1,10.1c-5.6,0-10.1-4.6-10.1-10.1c0-5.6,4.5-10.1,10.1-10.1C84.2,46.7,88.7,51.3,88.7,56.8z};
    }
}

\newcommand\orcidicon[1]{\href{https://orcid.org/#1}{\mbox{\scalerel*{
                \begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=-1,transform shape]
                    \pic{orcidlogo};
                \end{tikzpicture}
            }{|}}}}


\ifxetexorluatex % If you're using XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX,SmallCapsFeatures={Letters=SmallCaps,LetterSpace=5}]{Charis SIL}
\setsansfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Fira Sans}
\setmonofont{inconsolata}
\else % If you're using pdfLaTeX or latex
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{breakcites}
\usepackage{fbb}
\usepackage[type1]{cabin}
\usepackage[varqu,varl]{zi4}
\fi


\usepackage{csquotes}   

\includecomment{fullonly}   

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%  


\leftheader{%
    {\LARGE\bfseries\sffamily John Doe, PhD}
    
    \vspace{0.5cm}
    
    \makefield{\faUniversity}{\texttt{Institute of XXXXXXXX}}
    
    \makefield{}{\texttt{College of Engineering and Agro-Industrial Technology}}
    
    \makefield{}{\texttt{University of XXXXX}}
    
    \makefield{}{\texttt{XXXXXXX}}
    
    \vspace{0.3cm}
    
    \makefield{\faEnvelopeO}{\texttt{jdoe@email.com}}
    
    \makefield{\faPhone}{\texttt{+000000000000}}
    
    \vspace{0.3cm}
    
    \makefield{\orcidicon{0000-0000-0000-0000}}{\texttt{ORCiD:0000-0000-0000-0000}}
    
    \vspace{0.5cm}
}


\rightheader{~}
\begin{fullonly}
    \photo[r]{example-grid-100x100pt} %
    \photoscale{0.13}
\end{fullonly}

\title{Curriculum Vitae}

\begin{document}
    \makeheaders[c]
    
    \makerubric{grants}
    
\end{document}
```

**VerySimple.tex**

```
    % !TeX TS-program = pdflatex
        
    \listfiles
    \documentclass[a4paper,skipsamekey,11pt]{curve}
    
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    
    \RequirePackage{graphicx}   
    \RequirePackage{fontawesome}    
    \RequirePackage[dvipsnames,svgnames]{xcolor}
    \RequirePackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{shapes,shadows}
    
    \RequirePackage{comment}
    \definecolor{SwishLineColour}{HTML}{88AC0B}
    \definecolor{MarkerColour}{HTML}{B6073F}    
    
    \headerscale{1}
    \setlength{\headerspace}{6pt}
    \rubricfont{\Large\bfseries\sffamily}
    \setlength{\rubricafterspace}{-3pt}
    \setlength{\subrubricspace}{3pt}
    \setlength{\subrubricbeforespace}{4pt}
    \makeatletter
    \def\@@rubrichead#1{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]%\
            \shade[left color=SwishLineColour!60!white, right color=white] rectangle (\linewidth,2.5pt);
            \node[font={\@rubricfont},inner sep=0pt,text ragged,anchor=south west,text depth=.5ex,text height=1.5ex] at (1pt,2pt) {#1};
        \end{tikzpicture}%
        \vspace\rubricspace%
    }
    \makeatother
    
    \subrubricfont{\large\bfseries\sffamily}
    \subrubricalignment{l}
    
    \newcommand{\makefield}[2]{\makebox[1.5em]{\color{MarkerColour!80!black}#1} #2\hspace{2em}}
    
   %    \keyalignment{r}
    \rubricalignment{l}
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.25}  
    \newcommand{\makerubrichead}[1]{\vskip\baselineskip\@@rubrichead{#1}}
    
    \usepackage{lipsum} 
    
    \includecomment{fullonly}
    
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%      
    
    \leftheader{%
        {\LARGE\bfseries\sffamily John Doe, PhD}
        
        \vspace{0.5cm}
        
        \makefield{\faUniversity}{\texttt{Institute of XXXXXXXX}}
        
        \makefield{}{\texttt{College of Engineering and Agro-Industrial Technology}}
        
        \makefield{}{\texttt{University of XXXXX}}
        
        \makefield{}{\texttt{XXXXXXX}}
        
        \vspace{0.3cm}
        
        \makefield{\faEnvelopeO}{\texttt{jdoe@email.com}}
        
        \makefield{\faPhone}{\texttt{+000000000000}}
    }
    
    
    \rightheader{~}
    \begin{fullonly}
        \photo[r]{example-grid-100x100pt} %
        \photoscale{0.13}
    \end{fullonly}
    
    \title{Curriculum Vitae}
    
    \begin{document}
        \makeheaders[c]     
        \makerubric{grants}     
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Simon. It didn't work for me, however. I copied your code verbatim and ran it via TexStudio but it didn't work. I am still getting the "Overfull \hbox (82.29886pt too wide) in alignment" problem

Comment: May I know what tex editor are you using?

Comment: @ralph  TeXstudio

Comment: Thank you @Simon. I am also using TexStudio but it is not working. Am I missing something?

Comment: @ralph I added a file `VerySimple.tex` to test your environment. Put only this file and `grant.tex` it in a new working directory and compile. Keep me informed of the result.

Comment: Thank you very much @Simon. It worked initially, after following your instructions. However, once I modified the margins using the geometry package, I had the same problem again. Happened for both TexStudio and TexMaker. The odd thing is the error stuck even if I started from scratch using your example.